# google analytics, tracking a specific user

Tags: google-analytics

I want to be able to send people a link to my website and then track their navigation using Google analytics. So it will be like open link -> home -> 
about -> contact. So When I go to google analytics I can see which pages this specific user has visited. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is UTM tracking - there's a tool that helps you create custom track-able links available on https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/

If you want to see this data on a user level, for each of your users you need a link that has unique parameter values e.g.:

User 1: https://www.example.com/?utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_campaign=testCampaign&utm_content=user_1

User 2: https://www.example.com/?utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_campaign=testCampaign&utm_content=user_2

User 3: https://www.example.com/?utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_campaign=testCampaign&utm_content=user_3

Once your user accesses the link, you'll be able to distinguish him/her. To see the data and distinguish this user, you can create a custom report with the following configuration:

[image]